# render to index.html.twig after success registration FOSUserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

After a success registration i would to render to index.html.twig

So in class RegistrationController in the function registerAction i had by default:

```
 return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

So i change that to :

```
return $this->render('AcmeCovoiturageBundle:Index:index.html.twig'), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

but this caused error because i had informations in the index.html.twig from database.

so i rechange that to:

```
 return $this->render(controller("AcmeCovoiturageBundle:Index:index"), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

but i had this error: Attempted to call function "controller" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle\Controller"

Please review it and inform me how can i solve this error

Answer (score 1):

Finaly, i found a solution.
In First, i try to render to another page from registrationController. and it's not totaly wrong if i don't data showed in this page.
one of the contributors of FOSUserBundle reply on a question of this render and he said and i quote: "The login is not handled by FOSUserBundle at all, but by the Symfony security component. this bundle is about providing user management only"
So i search for another logic.
I create a listener. and i named it in the config.yml (projectname/SourcesFiles/app/config/config.yml)

```
services:
    fos_user.doctrine_registry:
        alias: doctrine
    sdz_user.registration_complet:
        class: Acme\CovoiturageBundle\Services\RegistrationConfirmListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

so the listener will be listen to the event subscriber from the symfony core.
After that, add a folder in your bundle and add a php class named RegistrationConfirmListener:

```
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $router;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
    $this->router = $router;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS  => 'onRegistrationSuccess'
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(\FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent $event) {
    $url = $this->router->generate('index');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

}

you will need the uses from FOSUserBundle:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface
```

be careful, if you don't put the namespace on the top, the symfony don't recognize your class.

```
namespace Acme\CovoiturageBundle\Services
```

did you see the "REGISTRATION_SUCCESS"? i take this from the registrationController from the function registraionAction:

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::**REGISTRATION_COMPLETED**, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

so, now try to test your listener if he is working or not by run this command :

```
php app/console container:debug |  app_user.registration_complet
```

and you will get this message on the console :

> [container] Information for service sdz_user.registration_complet
>       Service Id       sdz_user.registration_complet
>       Class            Acme\CovoiturageBundle\Services\RegistrationConfirmListener
>       Tags
>           - kernel.event_subscriber        ()
>       Scope            container
>       Public           yes
>       Synthetic        no
>       Lazy             no
>       Synchronized     no
>       Abstract         no
>       Done.

I don't made a solution for the login. this solution for registration. I think it will be the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your "index.htl.twig" file is located that you are referring to. I suspect it's in "default/index.html.twig" so try this:

```
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig'), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

The actual path is: app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig

Comment: Unable to find template "index/index.html.twig. i try with app/Ressources/views/default/index.html.wing and i got  Unable to find template "default/index.html.twig

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, maybe try `render('index.html.twig')` instead. Let me know, and I'll modify my post. The other thing is you need the twig template under that folder. For example if the directory "app/Resources/views/default" doesn't exist, you need to create it.

Comment: I found a solution and i post an answer here.